# JQUERY funções com callbacks nomeados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de criar uma função com Jquery de modo que eu pudesse passar somente o nome do callback e a especificação da função, assim como a função $.ajax, que como um exemplo, eu faço:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(){ alert("Sucesso") }
   error: function(){ alert("Erro") }
   ...
})
```

Atualmente estou fazendo assim:

```
var myFunction = function(myCallBack1, myCallBack2){
   ...
   if(...){
      myCallBack1(param);
   }else{
      myCallBack2(param);
   }
   ...
}

myFunction(
   function(param){ alert("callback 1" + param) }, 
   function(param){ alert("callback 2" + param) }
)
```

Ou seja, eu gostaria somente informar o nome da função e o que ela faz, assim como no ajax.

Pensei em definir a função recebendo um json de funções, com seus específicos nomes. Mas imagino que teria uma forma mais agradável de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um argumento só, `options`, e passar a declarar as funções dentro do objeto passado por parametro.

Por exemplo:

```
var myFunction = function(options){
   ...
   if(...){
      options.myCallBack1(param);
   }else{
      options.myCallBack2(param);
   }
   ...
};

myFunction({
   myCallBack1: function(param){ alert("callback 1" + param) }, 
   myCallBack2: function(param){ alert("callback 2" + param) }
});
```

Dependendo do cenário, será conveniente definir valores padrão para cada uma das callbacks ou propriedades caso não sejam informadas no argumento `options`:

```
function MyFunction(options){
  // mescla options com os parametros default
  options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
  ...
  if(...){
    options.myCallback1();
  }else{
    options.myCallback1();
  }
  ...
}

// valores default definidos caso não sejam 
// informados os parametros
MyFunction.prototype.defauts = {
  myCallback1: $.noop,
  myCallback2: $.noop
};
```

Comment: Entendi. Então é da forma que eu imaginava mesmo, rsrs. Muito obrigado!